# How to get dynamic columns for a query

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho

I want to create a SQL query which should generate columns according to date range. 
For example, if my input parameters for date range in `2013-01-01` and `2013-06-07`. Then the query should dynamically create seven month columns between these above two dates. The output should look like this:

`data` `column1` `column2` `Jan-13` `feb-13` `mar-13` `apr-13` `may-13` `jun-13` `jul-13`

I have tried couple of times but not reached to the desired result.

Please share your ideas on this. How should I proceed?

```
SELECT a.* ,
(SELECT SUM(fid1.TOTAL_AMOUNT)  FROM 
    fact_invoice_details fid1 
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dd.thedate, '%b %y') LIKE '%Jan%' ) AS 'Jan',
(SELECT SUM(fid1.TOTAL_AMOUNT)  FROM 
    fact_invoice_details fid1 
    where DATE_FORMAT(dd.thedate, '%b %y') LIKE '%Feb%' ) AS 'Feb'
FROM 
(
SELECT  DISTINCT gl.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        gl.NAME AS 'GL_Account_Name',
    di.account_id 'ACCOUNT_ID',
    dpp.company_name 'ACCOUNT_NAME',
    dd3.thedate AS 'INVOICE_DATE',
    di.OCCURRED_ON_DATE_ID,
    di.INVOICE_ID ,
    di.INVOICE_NUMBER ,
    fid.INVOICE_ITEM_ID,
    dpro.sku,
    dpro.PRODUCT_NAME,
    dci.ISO,
    fid.TOTAL_AMOUNT
    -- DATE_FORMAT(dd3.thedate, '%b %y') as mon
FROM     dim_gl_account gl
/* Some tables also having here */
WHERE dte.TENANT_ID = 155 
AND dd3.thedate BETWEEN CAST('2013-01-01' AS DATE)  AND CAST('2013-03-01' AS DATE)  ) a
```

as i can not paste the whole code .

Comment: Could you post the code for what you've tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. there are two dates which is the input parameters i need to create monthly buckets for all the transactions happened between these two dates.

Comment: Ok, so what data do you expect to see in the dynamically created month columns? The invoice date?

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to do is *pivot* the data from rows into columns. Unfortunately MySQL does not have this capability, however, we can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement to get a similar result.

```
SELECT
  cid,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(duedate) = 2013 AND MONTH(duedate) = 1 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS JAN_13,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(duedate) = 2013 AND MONTH(duedate) = 2 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS FEB_13,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(duedate) = 2013 AND MONTH(duedate) = 3 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS MAR_13,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(duedate) = 2013 AND MONTH(duedate) = 4 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS ARR_13,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(duedate) = 2013 AND MONTH(duedate) = 5 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS MAY_13,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(duedate) = 2013 AND MONTH(duedate) = 6 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS JUN_13,
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(duedate) = 2013 AND MONTH(duedate) = 7 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS JUL_13
FROM invoices
GROUP BY cid
```

### DEMO

Basically we supplied a `CASE` line for each month/year that we want to get the `SUM` for. You could include a line for each month/year and add back the date ranges to your `WHERE` clause but this would still create columns for all the months with zero values as seen [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6819b/1/0).

A better way to do this dynamically would be to use a prepared statement. This way we can supply our date range in the WHERE clause and let SQL do the heavy lifting.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN MonthYear = ''',
      MonthYear,
      ''' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS ',
      MonthYear
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM (
  SELECT
    cid,
    DATE_FORMAT(duedate, '%b_%y') MonthYear,
    total
  FROM invoices
  WHERE duedate BETWEEN CAST('2013-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2013-07-31' AS DATE)
  ORDER BY duedate
) src;

SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT cid, ", @sql, "
                   FROM (
                     SELECT
                       cid,
                       DATE_FORMAT(duedate, '%b_%y') MonthYear,
                       total
                     FROM invoices
                     WHERE duedate BETWEEN CAST('2013-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2013-07-31' AS DATE)
                     ORDER BY duedate
                   ) src
                   GROUP BY cid");

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

### DEMO

My examples are obviously much simpler then the snippet you provided but you should be able to incorporate the logic back into your queries. Depending on how you will be making calls you might also consider using a stored procedure as well. Finally, here is a link to an article discussing *pivot like* functions for MySQL.

[Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)